# Palindrome Partitioning (how to figure out how to use DFS)

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, dynamic, depth-first-search

My general question is how to figure out how to use DFS. It seems to be a weak part of my knowledge. I have vague idea but often get stuck when the problem changes. It caused a lot of confusion for me.

For this question, I got stuck with how to write DFS with recursion.
Given a string `s`, partition `s` such that every substring of the partition is a palindrome.

Return all possible palindrome partitioning of `s`.

For example, given `s = "aab"`,

Return

```
  [
    ["aa","b"],
    ["a","a","b"]
  ]
```

My first attempt was stuck in the loop of the helper function. Then from searching on internet, I found that  `bool palindrome(string s)`  can be written as a different signature.

```
bool palindrome(string &s, int start, int end)
```

This leads to the correct solution.

Here's the code of my initial attempt:

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool palindrome(string s)  
    {
        int len = s.size();
        for (int i=0;i<len/2; i++)
        {
            if (s[i]!=s[len-i])
              return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    void helper( int i, string s, vector<string> &p, vector<vector<string>> &ret)
    {
        int slen = s.size();
        if (i==slen-1&&flag)
        {
            ret.push_back(p);
        }


        for (int k=i; k<slen; k++)
        {
           if (palindrome(s.substr(0,k)))
           {
               p.push_back(s.substr(0,k));       //Got stuck
           }
        }
        i++;
    }

    vector<vector<string>> partition(string s) {
        vector<vector<string>> ret;
        int len=s.size();
        if (len==0) return ret;

        vector<string> p;
        helper(0,s,p,ret);
        return ret;
    }
};
```

Correct one:

```
    class Solution {
    public:
        bool palindrome(string &s, int start, int end)
        {
            while(start<end)
            {
                if (s[start]!=s[end])
                   return false;
                start++;
                end--;
            }
            return true;
        }

        void helper( int start, string &s, vector<string> &p, vector<vector<string>> &ret)
        {
            int slen = s.size();
            if (start==slen)
            {
                ret.push_back(p);
                return;
            }

            for (int i=start; i<s.size(); i++)
            {
                if (palindrome(s, start, i))
                   {
                       p.push_back(s.substr(start,i-start+1));
                       helper(i+1,s,p,ret);
                       p.pop_back();
                   }
            }
        }

        vector<vector<string>> partition(string s) {
            vector<vector<string>> ret;
            int len=s.size();
            if (len==0) return ret;

            vector<string> p;
            helper(0,s,p,ret);
            return ret;
        }
    };
```

**Edit Dec. 4, 2014:** I saw some approach using dynamical programming but can't understand the code completely.

esp. `isPalin[i][j] = (s[i] == s[j]) && ((j - i < 2) || isPalin[i+1][j-1]);`

Why `j-I<2` instead of `j-I<1`?

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<string>> partition(string s) {
        int len = s.size();
        vector<vector<string>> subPalins[len+1];

        subPalins[0] = vector<vector<string>>();
        subPalins[0].push_back(vector<string>());

        bool isPalin[len][len];

        for (int i=len-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
            for (int j=i; j<len; j++)
            {
                isPalin[i][j] = (s[i]==s[j])&&((j-i<2)||isPalin[i+1][j-1]);
            }
        }

        for (int i=1; i<=len;i++)
        {
            subPalins[i]=vector<vector<string>>();

            for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
            {
                string rightStr=s.substr(j,i-j);

                if (isPalin[j][i-1])
                {
                    vector<vector<string>> prepar=subPalins[j];

                    for (int t=0; t<prepar.size(); t++)
                    {
                        prepar[t].push_back(rightStr);
                        subPalins[i].push_back(prepar[t]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return subPalins[len];
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

What exactly are you asking? You have correct working code and your non-working code which is not that different.

I guess I can point out several issues with your code - may be it will be helpful to you:

1. in the `palindrome()` function you should compare `s[i]` to `s[len-1-i]` rather than to just `s[len-i]` in the `if`, since in former case you will compare 1st element (having index 0) to the non-existent element (index `len`). That might be the reason `helper()` got stuck.
2. in the `helper()` function `flag` is not initialized. In the `for` cycle, the end condition should be `k<slen-1` instead of `k<slen`, since in latter case you will omit checking the substring that includes the terminal symbol of the string. Also, incrementing `i` in the end of `helper()` is pointless. Finally, indentations are messy in the `helper()` function.

Not sure why you use DFS - what is the meaning of your graph, what are the vertices and edges here? As to how the recursion works here: in the `helper()` function you start checking substrings of increased length for being palindrome. If the palindrome is found, you place it into `p` vector (which represent your current partitioning) and try to break the remainder of the string into palindromes by calling `helper()` recursively. If you succeed in that (i.e. if the whole string is completely partitioned into palindromes) you place the contents of `p` vector (current partitioning) into `ret` (set of all found partitionings), and then clear `p` to prepare it for the analysis of the next partition (purge of `p` is achieved by `pop_back()` call that follows recursive call of `helper()`). If, on the other hand, you fail to completely break string into palindromes, the `p` is purged as well, but without transferring its content into `ret` (this is due to the fact that recursive call for the last piece of string - which is not a palindrome - returns without calling `helper()` for the final symbol and thus pushing `p` into `ret` does not occur). Therefore you end up having all possible palindrome partitionings in the `ret`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi~ this is my code using DFS + backtracking.

```
class Solution 
{
public:
    bool isPalindrome (string s) {
        int i = 0, j = s.length() - 1;
        while(i <= j && s[i] == s[j]) {
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        return (j < i);
    }

void my_partition(string s, vector<vector<string> > &final_result, vector<string> &every_result ) {
        if (s.length() ==0)
             final_result.push_back(every_result);
        for (int i =1; i <= s.length();++i) {
            string left = s.substr(0,i);
            string right = s.substr(i);
            if (isPalindrome(left)) {
                every_result.push_back(left);
                my_partition(right, final_result, every_result);
                every_result.pop_back();
            }
         }
    } 

vector<vector<string>> partition(string s) {
        vector<vector<string> > final_result;
        vector<string> every_result;
        my_partition(s, final_result, every_result);
        return final_result;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done Palindrome Partitioning using backtracking. Depth-first search was used here, idea is to split the given string so that the prefix is a palindrome. push prefix in a vector now explore the string leaving that prefix and then finally pop the last inserted element,
Well on spending time on backtracking is of the form, choose the element, explore without it and unchoose it.

```
enter code here
```

```html
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

bool ispalidrome(string x ,int start ,int end){
    while(end>=start){
        if(x[end]!=x[start]){
            return false;
        }
        start++;
        end--;
    }
    return true;
}

void sub_palidrome(string A,int size,int start,vector<string>&small, vector <  vector <  string > >&big  ){
    if(start==size){
        big.push_back(small);
        return;
    }
    
    for(int i=start;i<size;i++){
        if( ispalidrome(A,start,i) ){
            small.push_back(A.substr(start,i-start+1));
            sub_palidrome(A,size,i+1,small,big);
            small.pop_back();
        }
    }
}



vector<vector<string> > partition(string A) {
   int size=A.length();
   int start=0;
 
   vector <string>small;
   vector <  vector <  string > >big;
   
   sub_palidrome(A,size,start,small,big);
   return big;
}


int main(){
 vector<vector<string> > sol= partition("aab");

 for(int i=0;i<sol.size();i++){
  for(int j=0;j<sol[i].size();j++){
    cout<<sol[i][j]<<" ";
  }
  cout<<endl;
 
 }
}
```